# Почему не удаляется объект в С++?

Tags: классы, c++

Компилятор ругается на delete temp; Говорит что: ошибка: аргумент типа «class NOTE» задан для «delete»; должен быть указатель

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class NOTE {
  public:
    char name[50];
    char sername[50];
    int phone_number;
    unsigned birthday[3];

    ~NOTE();
     NOTE(char *Name, char *Sername, int number, unsigned *day);

};

NOTE::NOTE(char *Name, char *Sername, int number, unsigned *day)
{
    phone_number = number;
    memcpy(name, Name, sizeof(name));
    memcpy(sername, Sername, sizeof(sername));
    memcpy(birthday, day, sizeof(birthday));

}

NOTE::~NOTE()
{
    delete[]name;
    delete[]sername;
    phone_number = 0;
    delete[]birthday;

}

int main()
{
    char name[50];
    char sername[50];
    int phone_number;
    unsigned birthday[3];
    char cklava;
    int count = 1;

    FILE *outfile = fopen("text.txt", "w");
    cout << "Ввод данных (y/n)" << endl;
    cout << "y/n" << endl;
    cin >> cklava;
    if (cklava == 'y')
        while (true) {
            cout << "Введите имя человека" << endl;
            scanf("%s", name);
            cout << "Введи фамилию человека" << endl;
            scanf("%s", sername);
            cout << "Введи номер телефона" << endl;
            scanf("%d", &phone_number);
            cout << "Введи день рожденья этого человека дд.мм.гггг" << endl;
            cin >> birthday[0] >> birthday[1] >> birthday[2];
            NOTE temp(name, sername, phone_number, birthday);
            fwrite(&temp, sizeof(temp), 1, outfile);

            cout << "Ввод данных (y/n)" << endl;
            cout << "y/n" << endl;
            cin >> cklava;
            if (cklava != 'y') {
                delete temp;
                break;
            }
            ++count;
        }
    fclose(outfile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Правильно ругатся. Учите матчасть.

Comment: Больше ни че?

Comment: Ну может исправите..

Answer (score 1):

delete нужен для тех классов, которые созданы через вызов new, а в Вашем случае он сам удалится.
Но вызов `NOTE temp(name, sername, phone_number, birthday);` меня смущает.

Comment: А как можно в выделить в куче объект в этом случай с таким конструктором.

Comment: я не говорю, что это неверный вызов конструктора.

Comment: Ну я понял. как тогда с new сделать?

Comment: либо с new, либо убрать delete.

Comment: NOTE *temp = new NOTE;
        temp(name,sername,phone_number,birthday);

Comment: Все равно много ошибок... Вот одна из них
Без имени.cxx:54:26: ошибка: нет подходящей функции для вызова «NOTE::NOTE()»

Comment: @Ruzel, Вы в деструкторе пытаетесь удалить **часть** объекта, которая не создавалась через new. 

К только что написанному NOTE temp = new ... тот delete не имеет никакого отношения.

Еще раз повторяю - внимательно перечитайте книжку.

Answer (score 1):

> Почему не удаляется объект в С++?

Да, почему не удаляется? Очень даже удаляется! Причём безо всякого delete. Убери вообще все delete в программе. Они не нужны и вообще приводят к ошибке, потому что все данные хранятся на стеке. Да и вообще деструктор класса NOTE тогда не нужен.

> memcpy(name, Name, sizeof(name));

Ужас какой-то. Ещё один источник ошибок. Для копирования строк есть strcpy. Лучше заменить это на strcpy(name, Name) и остальные по аналогии. Конечно, это исправит не все ошибки и всё-таки останется лазейка для хакеров, но вряд ли это так существенно для этой программы.